# Mincom application hangs when trying to communicate with ttyUSB1

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, yocto-project

I have GSM module that enumerates as ttyUSB0 and ttyUSB1. I have installed minicom in my raspberrypi-cm3 image. When I try communicating with `/dev/ttyUSB1` 
The application hangs. I have restart the entire cm3 to close the application.

The commands that I have used to communicate with minicom are

```
minicom -o -s
```

The configuration is as follows

```
A - serial device : /dev/ttyUSB1
E - Bps/par/bits: 115200 8N1
F - Hardware flow control :NO
G - Software Flow contrl : No
```

The other command I used was

```
minicom -b 115200 -D /dev/ttyUSB1
```

I tried using minicom in Raspberry-pi buster image to the same module and it works.

Any Ideas what could be wrong?
Am I missing something in my yocto package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the issue. qmi_wwan module was utilizing the resource ttyUSB1 and because of that I wasn't able to communicate with the module. Once I blacklisted the qmi_wwan by creating a blacklist.conf file and restarted the module I was able to communicate via minicomm